# Unable to find JSP file creation option in Escllipse as well as Intellij

Tags: spring-boot

I have been trying creating a spring boot project, but when i tried creating a .jsp file, i didn't find the option for it. Can anyone help me with this. I even tried creating file manually but it gave me an empty document.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a webapp folder in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` where here all Jsp  file will be created. Then you need to tell the spring boot framework to load the Jsp file from this folder, by specifying

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

in application.properties file. Try some Hello World example I would suggest. Have a look at this link https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/